# how to update state from a response from a server in React native

Tags: json, react-native, jsonresponse

How can I update my `setBlogPosts` state by getting response from server? This code is not working but, I have checked that my server was working. I have called `setBlogPost` inside `useEffect` prop in my display file.I am new to React Native and so i don't know how to update state using data from server.

```
const getBlogPosts = () => {
    return async () => {
      const response =await jsonServer.get('/blogposts');
      setBlogPosts(response.data)

    }
  }
```

Comment: Ignore last 3 back ticks,added by mistake

Answer (score 1):

Define the state like this:

```
const [blogPosts, setBlogPosts] = useState();
```

and your getBlogPosts should be like this:

```
const getBlogPosts = async () => {
const response =await jsonServer.get('/blogposts');
setBlogPosts(response.data)
}
```

this should work. try checking blogPosts Value in useEffect :

```
useEffect(()=>{
console.log(blogPosts)
}, [blogPosts ]);
```

Comment: It is my pleasure. please mark this as accepted answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

Use spread operator:

```
this.setState({ blogPosts: this.state.blogPosts, ...response.data })
```